# Eclipse indexer runs every time I start my program

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-cdt, indexer

The Eclipse indexer runs from the beginning every time I start my C++ program. Indexing this large program takes 10 minutes so it would help productivity if it could reuse the index it generated before.

This is Eclipse Kepler (4.3.1) SR1 Build id: 20130919-0819 with CDT on Oracle Linux.

[edit] To clarify, I'd like to reuse the index instead of turning off the indexer altogether.

Comment: For me, it rebuilds the index every time I start Eclipse. Is this happening to you as well?

Answer (score 3):

Are you sure the indexer isn't running because you just did a build? By default Eclipse projects are set up to refresh the entire project after a build. I always set this to only refresh the directories that are affected by the output of my build process (e.g. "ProjectTopLevel/Build".

You can specify which path(s) the indexer will refresh after a build is completed:

1. Project -> Properties
2. Click on "C/C++ Build" in the tree on the left
3. On the right, select the "Refresh policy" tab
4. "Delete..." to remove the resource that points to your project's top level directory.
5. "Add resource..." and specify the directories that are affected by your build.

Comment: Good idea, but the name of the project is in the path. How can I make it relative to the current project?

Answer (score -1):

you can disable that option reading this link... [Disable Indexer C++](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/rtnlhelp/v6r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.cdt.doc.user/tasks/cdt_t_endis_indexer.htm)

Hope this works...

Reggards

Comment: To clarify, I'd like to reuse the index instead of turning off the indexer altogether.